# Wordpress Admin Users

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was trying to write an sql query for wordpress but why is my query very slow? it takes 3.5 seconds. im trying to copy the one under wordpress `wordpress/wp-admin/users.php` which selects users but its fast.

```
SELECT 
    usr.display_name,
    m1.meta_value,
    m2.meta_value
from wp_users usr
JOIN wp_usermeta m1 ON (m1.user_id = usr.id AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name')
JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON (m2.user_id = usr.id AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name') 
ORder by usr.user_login
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Is it your query either one you copied from users.php?

Comment: i made the query to copy how the wordpress query for users works

Comment: How many records does this pull? Are you displaying the first and last name?

Comment: in `wp_users` it has 8500 rows while in `wp_usermeta` it has 300k.

Comment: yes..im trying to display the first and last name also order by first and last name

Comment: The query in your question isn't ordering by first and last name. Please ensure the query in your question matches the query you're having issue with.

Comment: that query also has a problem. also when i add order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the query as given should be rather fast, since you're ordering on an index on the wp_users table, MySQL is able to locate the specific 30 records that you wish to pull.

MySQL only has to pull 30 records from wp_users, then do two lookups per record for the join (30 * 2 = 60). Unfortunately, each of those lookups require a table scan since the index on wp_usermeta.user_id only get them half way to the particular record they are trying to find. Still, since it's just 30 records (60 lookups), it should be rather fast. One way to improve this would be to add a compound index on wp_usermeta.user_id + wp_usermeta.meta_key, which would avoid the small table scan.

You may have even better success with a covering index, assuming the values are small enough to fit in the index "prefix", by creating a compound index on all three fields: wp_usermeta.user_id + wp_usermeta.meta_kety + wp_usermeta.meta_value.

However, when ordering by lastname, firstname, MySQL must pull all 8,500 records in your wp_users table, do all the lookups for the join (8,500 * 2 = 17,000 lookups) each of which must do a table scan, then order them in a temporary table, before it can locate the 30 records you want.

The solution here might be to create the same covering index as mentioned in the first part. You'd want to do a self-join on the wp_usermeta table and hope that MySQL actually uses its [index merge optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) to locate the 30 records you want, before doing a join back to the wp_users table:

```
SELECT 
    usr.display_name,
    m1.meta_value,
    m2.meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta m1
JOIN wp_usermeta m2
  ON (m1.user_id = m2.user_id AND m1.meta_key = 'lastname' AND m2.meta_key = 'firstname'
JOIN wp_users usr
  ON m1.user_id = usr.id
ORDER BY m1.meta_value, m2.meta_value
LIMIT 0,30
```

If that doesn't work out for you, then consider ordering only by last name, using a compound index on wp_usermeta.meta_key + wp_usermeta.meta_value.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW,

I think this is a simpler query...

```
SELECT u.display_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value END) first_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value END) last_name
  FROM wp_users u
  JOIN wp_usermeta m
    ON m.user_id = u.id 
 GROUP
    BY u.id
 ORDER 
    BY u.user_login
 LIMIT 0,30
```